# Unable to resolve babel-runtime/regenerator

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

Trying to run a react-native project but I am getting this error:

```
Unable to resolve "/Users/bobby/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator" from "App.js"
```

What are some possible solutions to this issue?

My iOS simulator is giving me a red screen and saying this:

> Unable to resolve module `/Users/bobby/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator` from `/Users/bobby/Desktop/mstore/src/App.js`: The module `/Users/bobby/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator` could not be found from `/Users/bobby/Desktop/mstore/src/App.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
>
> - `/Users/bobby/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)`
> - `/Users/bobby/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/index(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)`
>
> ABI28_0_0RCTFatal
>   **37-[ABI28_0_0RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke
>   _dispatch_call_block_and_release
>   _dispatch_client_callout
>   _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE**
>   __CFRunLoopRun
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific
>   GSEventRunModal
>   UIApplicationMain
>   main
>   start
>   0x0

Comment: what is your npm version?\

Comment: My npm version is 6.2.0 (npm -v)

Answer (score 2):

Update your npm:

```
npm i npm@latest -g
```

You need to reinstall the `babel-runtime`, you need to have babel-runtime@6 in your dependencies.

```
npm i babel-runtime
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have executed these commands. Still the same error.

Comment: I went into the directory, npm uninstall babel-runtime, and the npm i babel-runtime. Is this different than having babel-runtime@6 in dependencies, and how do I do this if so? Sorry, relatively new to npm.

Comment: Check the package.json and see the version of `babel-runtime`

Comment: The line in my package.json is exactly this: "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",

Comment: Yes it still does.

Answer (score 1):

install babel/poylfill and put it at the top of your app entry point

Answer (score -2):

Was on macOS Mojave (beta software). Downgraded to latest stable release version (High Sierra) and everything appears to be working now.